# Recursive merging of pandas dataframe from imported csvs

Tags: csv, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have seen similar questions being asked and responded to. However, no answer seems to address my specific needs.

The following code, which I took and adapted to suit my needs, successfully imports the files and relevant columns. However it appends rows onto the df and does not merge those columns based on keys.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r'./csv_weather_data'               
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) 
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=47, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=['Year','Month','Day','Hour','DBT'],) for f in all_files)
```

Typical data structure is the following:

```
Year     Month     Day     Hour     DBT
1989     1         1       0        7.8
1989     1         1       100      8.6
1989     1         1       200      9.2
```

I would like to achieve the following:

1. import all csv files contained in a folder into a pandas df
2. merge first 4 columns into 1 column of datetime values
3. merge all imported csv, using newly created datetime value as an index, and adding DBT columns to that, with each DBT column taking the name of the imported csv (it is the Dry Bulb Temperature DBT of that weather file).

Any advice?

Comment: You can merge the first three columns with `pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates={'Date':[0, 1, 2]})`, but what does an hour of 100 or 200 mean? This obviously isn't a 24-hour metric.

Comment: Thanks. 00 is for minutes (i.e. 200 is 2am and 2200 is 10pm).
Parse dates worked perfectly!
How can I set up a recursive merge now? Contrary to *pd.concat* which appends rows starting from a blank dataframe, with merge I understand there is a need for a first non-empty dataframe to be there

Comment: Is there any way to set an 'auxiliary' variable (say '*f1*') which, within the loop cycle, gets assigned with the first value of f?

Answer (score 0):

You should divide the problem in two steps:

First, define your import function. Here you need to define datetime and set is as index.

```
def my_import(f):

    df = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=47, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=['Year','Month','Day','Hour','DBT'],)

    df.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.apply(lambda x : str(int(x['Year']))+str(int(x['Month']))+str(int(x['Day']))+str(int(x['Hour'])), axis = 1), format = '%Y%m%d%H')
    df.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    df.set_index('Date')
    return df
```

Then you concatenate by columns (axis = 1)

```
df = pd.concat({f : my_import(f) for f in all_files}, axis = 1)
```

Comment: FLab, thank you very much for your answer. I have tried to run and get the following error.

`"ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0"`

Also, could you please help me understand what the formula would do:

`(lambda x : str(int(x['Year']))+str(int(x['Month']))+str(int(x['Day']))+str(int(x['Hour'])) `